# inverse kinematics target goes crazy when attempting to move or adjust pole target

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

i was trying to move my target for my right arm IK to be able to animate the way the arm bends but when i try to move it, it seems to move the same way no matter what way i move it. the same thing happens when i try to adjust the pole target angle in the forearm IK bone constraint settings. is there a fix for this so i can adjust the angle the arm bends?

edit : the target bone starts to act crazy if i change the pole angle from 90 and move the IK controller bone at all

Blend file : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1E_-5THNMKMcyYv-4S-FhQgV9Xg1EFvaY?usp=sharing

Comment: You have a dependency loop.  Your pole target can't be parented to a bone involved in the IK.

Comment: then how do i get the target bone to follow the arm (not the entire armature so the target bone follows the arm or is that not necessary?)

Comment: You can create an IK goal end bone outside of the chain and parent the pole to that end bone. Or don't parent it to the chain at all and animate it manually.